# Trying to get next and previous item in foreach loop in PHP in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get previous and next item in PHP in symfony and then assign their values to next and previous variables so that I can echo the values somewhere else in the page but not getting any sucess..!
Can you people help me out with the following code as ???

```
<?php
$next = "";
$previous = "";
foreach ($clinic_videos as $cv ) {

 $embed = $cv->getEmbed();
 $pos_vidStart = strpos($embed, "embed/");
 $pos_vidEnd = strpos($embed, "\"", $pos_vidStart+6);
 $embed = substr($embed, $pos_vidStart+6, $pos_vidEnd - ($pos_vidStart+6));

 echo "<pre>";
    echo $embed;
 echo "</pre>";
 } ?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
neSK9hACYPI
rzcEvUfNQ3Y
BxzP1ORj-3M
_lOZQwT3OU0
fgm4GQAlVIc
Hub-MpPIjr0
V0qYepvL5pU
PhBAzuKxob8
6VSg3gebcO0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access the previous item by its key in the array.
As you dont show it i assume it has ordered numeric indexes

```
foreach ($clinic_videos as $key => $cv ) {
    $previous = array_key_exists($key - 1, $clinic_videos) ? $clinic_videos[$key -1] : false;
    $next = array_key_exists($key + 1, $clinic_videos) ? $clinic_videos[$key +1] : false;

    if($previous){
      echo $previous;
    }

    echo $current;

    if($next){
      echo $next;
    }
}
```

i build in a check, because there is no previous at first el and no next at last el

Comment: Can you update it with previous to be the first one when there is no previous element at first and then back again same for the last element too to make it next the last element when there is no next element..!

Comment: i made an update for you to get an idea, at all the code is to give you an idea not a full working example, you should keep your $current variable, and if there is no previous / next the variable will be `false` so you can test it..