# How do I retain a previous value from a foreach, MySQL PDO loop?

Tags: mysql, foreach

My data is in MySQL, I prefer to use PDO, so I loop through the results with:

```
foreach( $db->($sql) as $row ) {
    $previous = ????;
    $counter = $row[counter];
    ...
}
```

But I need to keep the previous value of $counter for testing in the next loop. I tried using this previous SO question,

[Trying to get next and previous item in foreach loop in PHP in symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437431/trying-to-get-next-and-previous-item-in-foreach-loop-in-php-in-symfony)

but I don't understand how to translate its solution to my issue. Can someone please show me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I have undestood well. Do you mean this?

```
$previousCounter = 0;
foreach($db->($sql) as $row) {
    // here you can read $previousCounter value
    $counter = $row[counter];
   ...
   $previousCounter = $counter;
}
```

And if you want the full previous row:

```
// declare $previous
foreach($db->($sql) as $row) {
    // here you can read $previous value
    // not in the first iteration, but in all the others
    $counter = $row[counter];
    ...
    $previous = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Carlos In your first example the values of $counter and $previousCounter are always the same. So I tried a different variable;  $previousComment = '';
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $comment = "$row[comment]";
    $previousComment = $comment; } But the values here are always the same as well. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I guessed I was missunderstanding something as well :) First things first... "counter" is a field in "row", isn't it? If so, let's suppose that in row 0 counter field value is 3, for example, and in row 1 counter is 5. In the first iteration, in "..." position, $previousCounter value is 0 and $counter value is 3. Isn't it? In the second iteration $previousCounter is 3 and $counter is 5. It should be that way, so... why do you say both variables have the same value? There is something I am not understanding well, sorry.